# Is it haram to be asexual?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it haram to be asexual, having no sexual interest in anybody? If so, why is it? I am confused because normally asexuals are looked down upon when they simply just don’t have any sexual desires. Is it the same for Islam?

Answer (score 1):

It can never be haram to **be**. We **are** how God has made us.

Only what we **do** can be haram. In some cases but not in this case, it may also be haram not to do something.

God will not request sexual activity from somebody He has made without this desire.

So, the answer is: no, it can't be haram.